# PostgresSQL|Scala: Any efficient way to interact using different Users for different queries with heavy ACL use

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, ebean

My whole interest in PostgreSQL is driven by its ACL system which is really powerful.

To access the data in a Scala application I have two options in mind EBeans/JDBC or Slick FRM.

Our application is an enterprise one and has more than 1000 users, who will be accessing it simultaneously, having different roles and access permissions. The current connectors, I am aware of, ask for database username/password at the time of connection building, and I haven't found these providing any facility to change the username/password on the fly as we will be getting the user reference from session object of the user accessing our server.

I am not sure how much the title of the question makes sense, but I don't see recreating(or separately creating) a database connection for every user as an efficient solution. What I am looking for is a library or toolkit which lets us supply the interacting `sub-user/ROLE` in options parameter using which PostgreSQL can do its ACL enforcing/check on data/manipulation requested.

Comment: `lets us supply the interacting sub-user/ROLE in options parameter using which PostgreSQL`             -  What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @RobBygrave I meant that instead of supplying the user and getting the available login roles, can we provide the different users with every query?

Answer (score 0):

You can "impersonate" a user in Postgres during a transaction and reset just before the transaction is done using the [`SET ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set-role.html) or [`SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set-session-authorization.html) commands issued after establishing a database connection.